npm remove workspace from monorepo
Assuming I have an existing monorepo managed with plain NPM and configured with workspaces: ["packages/*"], how do I remove a package say packages/foobar?
My usual solution is to just git rm -rf packages/foobar followed by npm install to update package-lock.json.
However, this still leaves entries in package-lock.json that I need to remove manually:
    "packages/foobar": {
      "name": "@mycompany/foobar",
      "version": "1.2.3",
      "extraneous": true,
      "license": "MIT",
      "dependencies": {
        /* ... */
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        /* ... */
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">= 16",
        "npm": ">= 7"
      }
    },

What is the proper way to remove a workspace / package from a monorepo managed by NPM?

I think it is a known issue that NPM didn't really care about.
20 months ago, someone raised this issue and a PR to fix it to the NPM CLI GitHub repository, but no one approved it so far.
On the other hand, pnpm handles it flawlessly. This illustrates how much pnpm cares about its workspace feature compared to npm. Because of this, I decided to move away from npm and use pnpm instead.

I would also want to migrate npm to pnpm. Do you have any guidelines that I can start with?

As a start, you can use the pnpm import command.
If you encounter any issues, you may consult this blog post, which I found comprehensive enough.
https://www.raulmelo.me/en/blog/making-the-switch-to-pnpm
